# Como uso className con ternario en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quiero usar una clase que me viene por props segun que componente llame al componente en cuestion y, ademas, una clase condicional segun le llegue o no una prop. 
Lo hice de las siguientes formas

```
    className={`${(buttonStyle, disabled ? 'button-light-blue-small' : 'button-white-small')}`}
```

De esa forma no me toma el buttonStyle que le viene por prop.
Si hago lo siguiente:

```
     className={cn(buttonStyle, {
      'button-light-blue-small': disabled,
      'button-white-small': !disabled
    })}
```

Utilizando lo siguiente, me toma buttonStyle pero no el estilo condicional.

Como puede resolverse?

Comment: La razón es porque `disabled` es `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar una clase dependiendo de props, yo realizo lo siguiente:

```
className={`${buttonStyle} ${disabled ? 'class1' : 'class2'}`}
```

Parece que no estás utilizando la sintaxis correcta.

Comment: No. El está usando la librería [classnames](https://npmjs.com/package/classnames) la cual permite generar un string basado en condiciones.

Comment: El error que está obteniendo es porque `disabled` se está resolviendo como `undefined`. Cuando classnames detecta un `undefined`, ignora esa condición.

Comment: Por eso el uso de ternario, si disabled === undefined entonces "class2" es pasado.